# Permanently set permissions for /dev/ttyACM0 port using UDEV

Tags: ros, usb, permissions, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have an Hokuyo URG-04LX laser range finder and I'm using the hokuyo_node to read data from it. In order to use that ROS node, I have to set read-write permissions to the /dev/ttyACM0 port every time I plug in the laser. Searching on the web, I found that there is a way to store these permissions permanently using udev but unfortunately this procedure is not working for me.

This is what I get from lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 15d1:0000
```

and, since I'm in the plugdev group

```
federico@HP-Compaq-8200:~$ groups
federico adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

I created a file named 70-hokuyo.rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/, with the following line:

```
federico@HP-Compaq-8200:~$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-hokuyo.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="15d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0000", GROUP="plugdev", MODE:="0666"
```

but when I plug in the laser, I get always the same result:

```
federico@HP-Compaq-8200:~$ ls -l /dev/ttyACM0 
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 gen 13 12:49 /dev/ttyACM0
```

Please, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224028/permanently-set-permissions-for-/dev/ttyacm0-port-using-udev/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2016-01-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should be fine:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="15d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0000", MODE="0666", SYMLINK+="lidar_hokuyo"
```

This also adds a symlink as `/dev/lidar_hokuyo` so that you do not need to configure your port if it changes.

After you add this rule run:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && sudo service udev restart && sudo udevadm trigger
```

for changes to take effect.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on 2016-01-13**:
Thanks! It worked! The GROUP variable was messing up things :)

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-01-13**:
Glad it worked!